# API для обменника QIWI - BTC

Tags: api, users, bitcoin, qiwi

Подскажите пожалуйста, сейчас возникла потребность в реализации обменника QIWI - BTC.

Нужно достать API какого-либо сервиса, который работает с подобным. Не могли бы вы подсказать пару таких, возможно кто встречался с подобным.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Тебе не нужен апи. Возьми библиотеку xNet и сделай все по вебу. Или на кройняк компонент Webview vs Webbrowser.

Comment: Это слишком мучительно и долго) У многих обменников есть API, вот и хотелось бы узнать, возможно кто сталкивался с подобным